# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Account::set(double)

Tags: c++, class

I'm new to c++ classes and I'm practicing in vs code, here is the output in terminal

```
C:\Users\Sainath\Desktop\Classes>cl main.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30139 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30139.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Account::set(double)" (?set@Account@@QAEXN@Z) referenced in function _main
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

### Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Account ram;
    ram.set(200.00);
}
```

## Account.h

```
#pragma once
class Account
{
private:
    double balance;

public:
    void set(double bal);
    double get();
};
```

## Account.cpp

```
#include "Account.h"

void Account::set(double bal)
{
    balance = bal;
}
```

*I've observed that if I remove the **Account.cpp** and define the methods in **main.cpp** itself it doesn't throw back an error*
what should I do in order for the program to run without any errors?

Comment: Are you linking Account.cpp to your main.cpp?

Comment: you need to compile both cpp files then link them together into an executable

Comment: @WaisKamal no, I'm not linking my Account.cpp in my main.cpp, I've heard the instructor to say not to include .cpp files, include only .h files

Comment: @WaisKamal wait now my code is running, I've included Account.cpp in my main.cpp, thats kinda odd though the instructor i've been watching didn't include them, he even advised not to include them

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I am trying to say. You include the file when compiling, not within the code itself. For example, if I am compiling your code with gcc, I would use `g++ Main.cpp Account.cpp -o main.exe`.

Comment: @WaisKamal now it's working thanks a lot